# 2 Accounts should be merged - StackOverflow and Salesforce

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have 2 accounts.. one in StackOverflow and Salesforce. Both should be combined.  can we already do it? How? Any option?

Few of my questions are in Salesforce and others in stackOverflow.  Even  my reputation is different in both. Please help to combine.

Answer (score 7):

Your account is Stackexchange - You can not merge the sites that you are active in.

You are active in 2 sites: Salesforce and Stackexchange

[image]

Some users have as many as 30+ sites that they are active in, but only 1 user.

If you want higher reputation, just be more active :-)